# How to decompose Dirac spinor into plane wave solutions?

Tags: field-theory, fourier-transform, fermions, dirac-equation, spinors

Suppose that we know Dirac spinor $\psi$ (as complex numbers) in every point in 3d space (4th dimension is time)

How do we decompose it into plane wave solutions $u^s(p) e^{ipx}$ and $v^s(p) e^{ipx}$?

I understand that it would be some kind of fourier transform

P.S. I'm making a computer program, so the 3d space is discrete and it'd be very appreciated if you use discrete decomposition